# What is are the best ways to handle Lumen API memory exhaust error

Tags: laravel, api, post, get, lumen

I am involving with Lumen API development. This API works as a data source for a few other applications. These applications pulling data from this API. So there are some requests where the API provides a lot of data. For example, Table A has more than 20,000 records. Some have more than that. When API's table has more and more records, It gives '**Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)**' error. I would like to know what are the best ways to solve this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Chances are you need to look into the `chunk` function. I suspect you're trying to do `Foo::all()` or something else that loads an entire table into memory.

Comment: use paginate instead of get/all

Comment: @Demonyowh: I am using resource collections. When I use a resource collection, paginate links are not showing in the response